# Samba working via Nautilus, but not via mount

Tags: mount, permissions, samba

I am having a Samba share on a bananapi. On the pi I have created the user `samba`. Since the shares are also shared by owncloud, I have added `samba` to the group `www-data`.

If I am using Nautilus with the command `smb://samba@cavalorn/data/` everything works just fine. I can read, write and navigate in every folder.

Then I want to add the shares to the `fstab`. I did this by adding the following line to the file:

`//cavalorn/data /media/data cifs credentials=/home/daniel/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 0 0`

With correct credentials in the referenced `.smbcredentials` file.

If I am using `mount -a` no error if thrown and the folder appears in the launcher. But I am not able to read or write any data.

Why can Nautilus do it, but mount somehow broke. Doesn't mount try to use samba as a user?

PS: I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Since I want to mount the shares automatically...

Comment: I'm not an expert but I mount samba shares in fstab and they work.  My fstab line differs from yours in that I have permissions set to 0777 instead of 0770, and I have `uid=myusername,gid=myusername` in the line as well.  I am not sure what these differences mean, only that they work for me.

Comment: I noticed that at my mount point the folders are listed as `root:root`, where it actually should be `www-data:www-data`

Comment: That could be a factor too.  The mount points I use for the samba shares are listed as `myusername:myusername` whereas the mount points for my internal drives are `root:root`  They all have the same permissions though, `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Thanks using uid and gid solved it. At first I tried to use the uid and gid of the remote machine, but I have to use the ids of my local machine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Organic Marble mentioned in the comments, the problem was, that the folder was mounted with `root:root`, so my user could not read or write it. Using `uid` and `gid` in my `fstab` mounted it as `daniel:daniel`.